# Are questions about third party paid addons on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I have been looking into using stackexchange for Q&A about our own addons, However the questions we get so far are mostly related to blender itself and actually we do not get so many questions anyways.

So would it be okay to ask/answer questions related to third party Blender addons in the blender.stackexchange community? And ask users to tag the questions with the addon name?

Comment: What exactly about them? Using them? Asking if there is such an addon? Writing them?

Comment: Related: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/267/599

Comment: I mean questions which raise from the usage of third party addons. In most cases these questions are closely related to blender's usage in general. So i thought maybe it makes sense to answer these questions in the context of blender.stackexchange.

Comment: I don't see why not..

Comment: well our Addon is "commercial" in the sense of we sell it. That might annoy users. However i believe stackexchange is an awesome way to share knowledge. I thought about setting up our own stackexchange community. But that will most probably fail because of too few users and too few questions.

Comment: People are constantly asking questions on the interaction of blender and commercial packages like Unity, 3Dstudio or Maya or AfterFx.

Comment: @GaiaClary I can see what you mean because Blender is free but that doesn't mean we have to tie ourself to that regarding this community so its fine. Here on SE there are several sites that are based around a commercial application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This site is about Blender and ***anything*** Blender related as long as it's [allowed in our scope](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), commercial or free though we would more prefer the latter, I don't see why not. So that would include addons such as BlenderCookie's Contour, Unity interactions or even getting VRay configured etc .